# Is linux software raid recoverable if independent OS drive fails?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

From my understanding RAID controllers are responsible for managing reads / writes to and from RAID arrays since data for certain configurations (5 and 10 come to mind) can be sharded across multiple drives. I know many higher end servers will include an independent RAID card for the sole purpose of this management and that if that card goes out...you're in trouble. However, I'm unsure how this information is tracked via linux software raid.

I will first provide an example of the hardware setup prompting my question.

- PC001 is built to include four drives, drive001, drive002, drive003 and drive004
- drive001 exists as an OS drive (some flavor of linux) in a non raid configuration
- drive002, drive003 and drive004 are configured via linux software RAID as array001 using RAID 5

Questions:

1. On which drive is the information stored which linux requires for array001 to function? drive001 or array001?
2. If drive001 goes down, would you be able to install a new OS drive (drive005) with a new version of linux and continue using array001 as if nothing happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had that exact same set up and actually lost the OS drive and the ability to recover by moving to new HW, etc. is one of the things I really like about mdadm/software raid.

The config for the raid array is on Drive001 (as part of OS, file is actually `/etc/mdadm.conf`).

If the OS drive dies, replace drive, reinstall OS, update, install `mdadm` tools, re-create `/etc/mdadm.conf` with the array definition, and tell the system to activate it/reassemble it.  You'll be back up and running right quick.

From what I recall when my drive died I simply used apt-get to install the mdadm management stuff and the dpkg configuration steps asked about volumes required for boot, autostarting, etc. Answered appropriately and rebooted.  Can only assume it ran a similar scan...

And a note on scanning and assembling from the man page - the second sentence especially..

> When **--assemble** is used with **--scan** and no devices are listed, mdadm
>   will first attempt to assemble all the arrays listed in the config
>   file. If no arrays are listed in the config (other than those marked
>   ) it will look through the available devices for possible
>   arrays and will try to assemble anything that it finds. Arrays which
>   are tagged as belonging to the given homehost will be assembled and
>   started normally. Arrays which do not obviously belong to this host
>   are given names that are expected not to conflict with anything local,
>   and are started "read-auto" so that nothing is written to any device
>   until the array is written to. i.e. automatic resync etc is delayed.

Comment: So losing the original `mdadm.conf` file on `drive001` does not matter? The new os can rebuild the array with all data intact and continue to use it as if nothing had happened? (pretty sure that's what you stated)

Comment: @nullReference yes.  Editing answer to embetter it.